# node, express, body-parser - can't read js file from src

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

may be its dumb question but I can't find answer yet. :(
I made app using `create-react-app`, and server file:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
const p = path.parse(__dirname);

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const filePath = path.join(p.dir, 'src', 'index.js');
  fs.readFile(filePath,  {encoding: 'utf-8'},(err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } 
    res.send(data);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Started at port ${PORT}`);
});
```

tryied to read index.js file from app src directory but all i got in browser is plain text. I can only run static files from public directory. What i did wrong and how should i run js files of react app using express in node?

Comment: Are you trying to send a JSON data?

Comment: may be I don't understand how express server work. :/ Just want to see result of my index.js file in browser. Like when I use conmand npm start - I got result at http://localhost:3000/, but when I start my server file -  in browser at http://localhost:3000/ I got only plain text of my /src/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the `index.html` file that is built by react. A browser can only open a web page from a html file.

You need to first build your react app using `npm run build`

Then serve it with express with something like

```
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile('/build/index.html'); // wherever react creates the index.html
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't react take care of that when you create it with `create-react-app` ?

Comment: If you are referring to serving the app, then yes with `create-react-app` you can run `npm start` that will build the files (and rebuild when they are changed) and start a webserver. A react app has to be built before it can be run by the browser, `create-react-app` just gives to the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

To give you a basic idea on express,

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index') // index is an html file or a template (ejs, hbs, etc..)
})
// You can't directly send js files

app.get('/info', (req, res) => {
    res.render('info', {
      title: 'info page',
      message: 'welcome to the info page'
    })
})
// You can't directly send js files
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port 3000.')
})
```

If you want to send json

```
const leaderboardHistory = require("relativepath/leaderboardHistory.json")

app.get("/leaderboardhistory", function(req, res){
    res.render("leaderboardhistory", {leaderboardHistory : leaderboardHistory});
});
```